How was cloning photography done in the past?
Photos where a single person appear twice is quite common during the film era in my country. I see that trend a lot in '80s-'90s photos. Of course they're quite simple, mostly 2 halves like in the below sample, each half containing one people. They're usually captured in tourist areas by professional photographers.

Nowadays it's trivial to do with Photoshop or other editing apps or even AI, but I don't know how it can be done with a film camera. Some people said that they put a rotating cap that's half open on the lens, and exposure is done twice with the cap cover each half of the film. But I don't think that's true because even if you cover part of the lens then light photons still touch the whole film area
So how was it done?

Is it worth describing the same output using darkroom techniques?  Or is printing the picture outside the scope of the question ?

It is called double exposure.
It can be done in different moments in different ways.
I. During the taking of the photo.

Some cameras have a switch that allows the "cranking" of the shutter button but does not advance the film. This way you could expose again the same frame.

On the big circle is the film advance lever. On the small circle, it is a small nudge, that prevented the advancement of the film but still prepared the mechanism for the next shot when using the main lever. Nikon FM.


If you simply expose the film with the girl switching places you will have an overexposed image and a ghostly girl in both frames because the background is also exposed, so you need a device to mask two zones. This could be a black cardboard box with a movable window.
I believe I saw some attachments that you could put in front of your lens, like a lens hood. In fact you can prepare a lens hood for this effect with two barn doors. It could be an interesting DIY project.


The advantage is that, if done right you could send your film to be developed and printed anywhere. It could be done in slide film.
To control the blurriness of the exposures you need to change the distance to the front of the lens, and the aperture. The closer and the wider the opening, the blurrier.

Remember to use a tripod.

II. When exposing the paper.

Take two photos using a tripod.
During the paper exposure, you use the black box with a window and expose the two parts in two different stages. The reason for using a box is the same as controlling the distance of the first case. You have some separation against the paper you have a small transition zone that fades the two photos.
Develop the paper.

One problem is that you do not have much control on how to align the negative vs the prior exposure. You could mark some reference points before exposing the paper.
It is only done in one copy of the paper. It also means that a lot of people could only make them in a black-and-white copy.
III. Just print two photos and cut and paste

Use a sharp blade and some glue.


https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_FM#/media/Archivo:Nikon_FM_(top_view).jpg

Double exposure does not work so well when the background is brighter than the subject (e.g., as in the OP's photograph.)

That is why you use a masking device.

P.S., Nice Nikon F2. Damn! Those were beautiful cameras!

@Rafael Masking device would only work if it were at the focal plane. Anywhere else it would not be sharp, the uncovered half of the lens would expose most if not all of the frame, and there would be a ghost image to a greater or lesser extent.

How come the masking device does not leave a clear boundary at the edge of the two exposures?

You need to explore the distance to the front of the lens. When taking the photo, the closer to the front of the lens the blurryier, and when exposing the paper, the further away from the paper. And Mark, yes, a transition is desirable.

@MarkMorganLloyd: It's often advantageous to have the masking device not be in the focal plane, if the portion of the image which will change is not near the mask line.  If overall scene lighting remains constant, exposing film with part of an arbitrary plane between the camera and subject blocked off, and then with the opposite part of that plane blocked off, will create the same exposure pattern on the film as would a single exposure with nothing blocked off.  If the mask is at the focal plane, however, any inaccuracies in the mask will be in focus.  If, however, the mask is...

...much closer to the camera than to the focal plane, then any inaccuracies will be blurred.  Even more importantly when doing outdoor shooting, an in-focus mask will create a hard boundary if the lighting changes between shots; an out-of-focus mask will create a gradient between the two differently-lit exposures.

Although I do not use film anymore, I'll do a proof of concept and explore the correct way of merging two shots simulating what would happen during a film exposure.

Image masking is a technique used in photo editing to separate or isolate specific areas of an image from the rest, allowing for more precise editing and manipulation. Essentially, it's like placing a “mask” over the parts of a picture you want to protect or hide while exposing the other areas for editing
Image masking was used by still photo darkroom technicians and a flying mask was used by Cine editing technicians. A high contrast film was made by contract printing a copy of the original negative on high contrast film. Two masks were made, one negative and one positive.
The mask was opaque in some areas and clear film in other areas. The mask isolated specific areas to the picture. In other words the mask protected the printing paper from being exposed during the printing operation.
A second exposure, using a reverse mask allowed the technician to superimpose a different image onto the printing paper.
Masking was an art form.


Some people said that they put a rotating cap that's half open on the lens, and exposure is done twice with the cap cover each half of the film. But I don't think that's true because even if you cover part of the lens then light photons still touch the whole film area

That is basically how it was done. You are correct that if you mask the objective element all parts of the image circle are still projected onto the image plane if the mask is in contact with the lens element. And if the mask is extremely close you will still get a complete image circle, but with some vignetting. I.e. an objective element of any size/shape projects a complete image circle.
However, if the mask is some small distance in front of the objective element it records as a black (out of focus) object occupying that portion of the field of view instead. So the area occupied by the mask/black object on the image plane receives no/minimal light; leaving it available for the second exposure.
It's actually also possible to do a double exposure over the entire image frame in a similar manner. I.e. expose a silhouette (black area/object) with the first exposure, and something brighter occupying the same area with the second... That's essentially what using flash does, it combines a first ambient exposure with a second flash exposure; and whatever is brightest appears "on top."
This example shows how where the two exposures combine (light + light) you get overexposure, and a "normal exposure" in the silhouette/black object area with the second exposure on top (more visible). (SOURCE)

Rafael noted the winder release that allowed cocking the shutter for the second exposure without advancing the film, which made this possible.

Creating such montages is relatively simple.
First way:

mask half of the paper
expose
move the mast to the exposed already part of the paper
expose
washing, fixation (not sure about the terminology :) )

Second way:

expose first negative
change paper
expose second negative
washing, fixation
use one of the image as background, cut second one and glue it on the first
take a photo
washing, fixation
expose
washing, fixation

The second way give you the opportunity to make fine transition between the photos and align them better.

Your "second way" can be surprisingly effective. (Don't ask me how I know!)

Simplest way is to use an electronic flash with a very distant or dark drape as background.  Many 35mm SLRs film cameras from the 80's had multiple exposure buttons that locked the film in place when recharging the shutter. Minolta SRT303 for eg.  Otherwise you had to turn the rewind crank back a bit to prevent the film from being shifted.
The flash with its own sensor would make the exposure identical for each shot, so there would be no tricky post-processing.
I think some Canon cameras had 2nd curtain synch option, rather than the more common 1st curtain. The flash would fire when the 2nd curtain started its travel.  This would make the ambient light look like it was trailing the subject instead being in front.

The old, old in-camera way to do this worked best indoors (and was included in one or more of Kodak's home photography books).  You'd position your subject in a lit area with a darkened area in frame, expose, then double expose with the subject in the previously darkened area, now lit and the original lit area darkened.  Done well, it looks as good as a Photoshop job, and requires no special equipment except a camera that can make double exposures (which was most of them when this technique was common), a tripod, and some means of controlling lighting and exposure accurately.
